# API for webapp and mobile app and SESSION variables

Tags: php, api

I have a dating site.. so users need to sign up and sign in to chat we others.

My website is made in HTML and PHP and when a user is logged in, i use $_SESSION.

But my new site (v2), will use a JS FrameWork with calls to my api.

So my first question is about this API... Should i use $_SESSION in my API to find out which user is logged in?

And the second part of my question is.. After my webapp will be done, i will start the mobile app and i was wondering if i can use the SAME API Or it is better to use another api dedicated to the mobile app ?

By aPI i mean all file to interact with the user (entry point, routes, controllers, models... )

So one API for mobile app and my web app? or it is better to have an api for each app

Pascal

Comment: Why would you consider two API's for this? API's are designed to return raw data - The front-end decides what to do with this data.

Comment: Use authentication by JWT for your API, you can store claims within the token

Comment: `Should i use $_SESSION in my API`...you can, but most web APIs, especially if they're designed on REST principles, are usually stateless. They usually use token authentication instead. There's no reason your front-ends can't use the same API...and it would be a lot more efficient in terms of coding effort. It's kind of one of the good things about having an API - consolidate all the business logic in one place, and then build as many front-ends as you like to target different environments, without having re-write your whole application logic every time.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your answer. I also asked another small question below... in the first answer ! Maybe your answer can help me ! thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

API's meant to be stateless and need to have JWT or other stateless token based mechanisms to perform authentication.

You can use token based authentication for both web and mobile apps.

For JWT authentication you can use one of the packages listed on: https://jwt.io/libraries?language=PHP

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... i understand. But one more question please... is Token JWT are slower than var session ? Sorry if my question seems strange to you but with session, we just need to do session_start() and then, we can use it... So with a token, we need to encode it the first time.. and to pass it to every http request, and we need to decode it.... so, does decoding a token take longer than session variables. Again, thank you so much !

Comment: JWT doesn't use sessions to authenticate users.

It just adds a header to subsequent requests, which will be an [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header.

You're not able to use SESSION vars because there is no sessions will be available for AJAX, REST API calls (Event if you session_start).

This is why because the login request will not save a session cookie and send it back to server to authenticate subsequent requests.

Refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/session-vs-token-based-authentication/

Comment: JWT is slower than SESSIONS? Nope. Decoding and sending JWT to the server is not a resource hungry task and even in sessions a session cookie is sent along with the request. For decoding, use libraries to do decoding. They can handle it. For example, if you want to use `axios` as a request library, it has a plugin to handle JWT - [axios-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-jwt)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answer ! It helps me a lot ! Have a great day !